# Perl + LFTP Multiline Commands

Tags: perl, bash, shell, ftp, lftp

I was porting one of my existing scripts into perl and ran into some difficulty with executing system commands (specifically lftp). Here is how I did it in bash:

#### BASH:

```
lftp -u $ftpusername,$ftppass -e open $hostname << EOF
      set ftp:ssl-allow no
      set mirror:use-pget-n 5
      glob -a rm -r "${remote_dir}/file.php"
EOF
```

So I'm wondering how I can execute this exact same command in Perl. Here's what I've tried with no avail:

#### Perl:

```
system("lftp -u $ftpuser,$pass -e open $hostname
            set ftp:ssl-allow no
            set mirror:use-pget-n 5
            glob -a rm -r 'remote_dir/db-import.php'"
      );
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### perl: feeding stdin of executed command

You may use `open` to open pipe to executed program (`lftp`) input.

```
open( my $LFTP,'|-', "lftp -u $ftpuser,$pass -e open $hostname" ) 
  or die "Cannot open lftp: $!";
print $LFTP <<"END";
set ftp:ssl-allow no
set mirror:use-pget-n 5
glob -a rm -r 'remote_dir/db-import.php'
END
close($LFTP) or die; # die unless lftp exit code is 0
```

---

**Alternative method**: Using module like [`IPC::Run`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) allows to check executed command replies.

Comment: This works, although I had to make a few syntax changes to the code. I think you missed a couple semi-colons. Thank you!

Comment: I have added some semicolons :-)